Proverb request: "Live within your means."
This is a  saying in India. It literally means:
"spread your legs only as much as the blanket allows."
It is advice to live within your means. Avoid overspending and taking on debt to avoid having non-repayment issues.  Credit card holders be aware.
What is an English equivalent to this proverb?

"Live within your means" might be the best!

I agree with Andy, but also "Never spend money before you earn it"  -  attributed to various US founding fathers (Jefferson, Franklin) but simple enough that it was probably coined many times by many people.

Remember that the best reason to learn proverbs is so you can avoid them, as most are clichéd and just make you look lazy or like a non-native speaker.

This is not exactly the same, but it's similar:

Don't bite off more than you can chew.


Cut your coat according to your cloth.

It is only occasionally possible that there would be same proverb. But generally you will find proverbs where meanings match, hence it can be used for similar situations.

There's the folksy saying, though not quite a proverb in status:

Don't have champagne tastes when you have a beer pocketbook.


Yes, often used to describe somebody who overspends on expensive goods - "champagne tastes on a beer budget".
